# page-break-before: always is freezing print dialog box

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, report

I have an html page that generates a bunch of tables. I need to see this page on the screen as well as be able to print it. When I print, I want to make sure that each table begins in a new piece of paper.

To accomplish this I am using a `page-break-before: always` css rule for the h4 tag. However, this is causing the print dialog to freeze before loading the preview and the only way out is to close the tab.

Does anyone know why this may be happening and how to get around it. If there is a better approach to printing something, I'd like to know that as well. Thanks!

Here is my code:

show.html.erb

```
<html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Table Page -->
  
    
    <% @reports.each do |report| %>
    <% next if report[1].empty? %>
    <div class="page-tables">
    <!-- Table -->
    <div class="table-responsive">
    

      
        <h4><%= report[0] %></h4>
      <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <th><%= report[0] %></th>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Other columns</th>
             
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <% report[1].each do |line| %>
          <tr>
              <td><%= line[0] %></td>
              <td>Other columns</td>
        </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
        
     </table>
      <br>
       <% end %>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and my .css files

```css
@media print {

h4{
  page-break-before: always;
}



tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #E2E1E1 !important;
  }




}
```

Things I've noticed:
  - When I reduce the number of tables generated in the report, no freezing happens
  - If I keep a high number of tables but remove the css rule for `page-break-before:always` there is also no freezing 
 - the striped css rule is not causing issues

Other notes, not sure if relevant:
- I developing on Chrome
- The back end for this is a rails app
-There are about 20 tables, with an average of 20 rows each. They are loading fine on the screen. Issue is only when I do cmd+p to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what was causing the issue was that my `</div>` closing tags were after the `<%end%>` erb tag.  I fixed this and it works now.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


</head>

<body>
  <!-- Table Page -->  
  <% @reports.each do |report| %>
    <% next if report[1].empty? %>
    <div class="page-tables break-before-table">
    <!-- Table -->
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <h4><%= report[0] %></h4>
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
            <th colspan="11"><%= report[0] %></th>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% report[1].each do |line| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= line[0] %></td>
                
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>   
  </body>
```